# Actions after validation of email in form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have following piece of code to validate email address :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_email(field,alerttxt)
{
  with (field)
  {
    apos=value.indexOf("@");
    dotpos=value.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (apos<1||dotpos-apos<2) 
    {
      alert(alerttxt);
      return false;
    }
    else {return true;}
  }
}
function validate_form(thisform)
{
  with (thisform)
  {
    if (validate_email(email,"Not a valid e-mail address!")==false)
    {
      email.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
```

Now in the body part, I have added

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit=validate_form(this) id="teacher_form">
</body>
```

What happens here is, If email address is wrong , it shows a popup with the message but then the form is accepted. What can be solution for stopping from the form being accepted after the alert has been displayed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)" id="teacher_form">
</body>
```

The validation function is returning `false` as it should, but it is not also being returned by the `onsubmit` event handler. Both of these things need to happen in order to prevent the form from being submitted.